# Can't resolve hostname when docker is running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, git

I'm currently running Ubuntu on a `WSL2`, I have a couple of repos I cloned with my ssh key (which is valid as I registered it on Azure as I'm using Azure Repos).

Right now, if I start WSL and try cloning a new repository, nothing out of the ordinary happens. But, whenever I start my docker service on WSL (using `sudo service docker start`), out of sudden, whenever I try `git clone`, `git pull` or any git command, I'm getting the following message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.dev.azure.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I was able to confirm that this is indeed because of docker because if I stop wsl and start it again, everything works just fine until I start docker again.

That's not a terrible issue, but it's extremely annoying, so I would appreciate a solution and an explanation as to why this is happening since I've not a single clue on what is causing this behaviour.
Probably worth mentioning: If I try to stop docker service, it does not work until I restart wsl

Comment: What are you running inside the container?

Comment: Right now, nothing... I just removed every image and network on my docker and it's still happening.

Comment: So the container contains nothing? Something is alternating your DNS. Something isn’t adding up.

Comment: It's weird, indeed! I was able to fix it by creating a resolv.conf on my /etc/ directory and adding 0.0.0.0 and 8.8.8.8 to it, but I'm still intrigued as to why that happened.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that, before creating it, there was no resolv.conf, which might indicate that docker was removing it and WSL was recreating it when I restarted it?

Comment: Yes; By default that file isn’t created. By creating it you create a static configuration